# Is it expected that terraform does not wait for the module to be fully applied when that module is a dependency of the resource?

Tags: terraform

Consider the following terraform snippet:

```
module "aks_cluster" {
  source                     = "git::ssh://git@ssh.dev.azure.com/..."
  key_vault_id               = module.keyvault.keyvault_id
  ...
}
```

From this I conclude that the module `aks_cluster` depends on the module `keyvault`.

However, when running apply I can see the following:

```
module.aks_cluster.module.aks_cluster.tls_private_key.aks_ssh_key["aks1"]: Creating...
module.aks_cluster.module.aks_cluster.tls_private_key.aks_ssh_key["aks1"]: Creation complete after 0s [id=fe71f0acb5c598e1d1cc1dbef7e732ef35c9648c]
module.aks_cluster.module.aks_cluster.azurerm_user_assigned_identity.private_aks["aks1"]: Creating...
module.aks_cluster.module.app_insights.azurerm_application_insights.app_insights["ai01"]: Creating...
module.aks_cluster.azurerm_resource_group.onboarding: Creating...
module.aks_cluster.module.keyvault.azurerm_key_vault.keyvault: Creating...
module.aks_cluster.module.lga.azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.lga: Creating...
module.aks_cluster.azurerm_resource_group.onboarding: Creation complete after 1s [id=...]
module.aks_cluster.module.aks_cluster.azurerm_user_assigned_identity.private_aks["aks1"]: Creation complete after 3s [id=...]
module.aks_cluster.module.aks_cluster.azurerm_role_assignment.private_aks_dns_contributor["aks1"]: Creating...
module.aks_cluster.module.aks_cluster.azurerm_role_assignment.acr_pull["aks1"]: Creating...
module.aks_cluster.module.aks_cluster.azurerm_role_assignment.private_aks_network_contributor["aks1"]: Creating...
module.aks_cluster.module.app_insights.azurerm_application_insights.app_insights["ai01"]: Still creating... [10s elapsed]
module.aks_cluster.module.keyvault.azurerm_key_vault.keyvault: Still creating... [10s elapsed]
...
```

It looks like the `aks_cluster` module resources are being created at the same time as those of the `keyvault`.

I am pretty sure when resource X references a property on a resource Y it means X depends on Y, but it does not seem to work this way for modules.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within the `aks_cluster` module, only the resource(s) that references the `keyvault_id` will have a dependency on the spesific resource(s) in the `keyvault` that is used to create the module output.

If you want to force a dependency on the module you can use `depends_on`:

```
module "aks_cluster" {
  source                     = "git::ssh://git@ssh.dev.azure.com/..."
  key_vault_id               = module.keyvault.keyvault_id
  ...

  depends_on = [
    module.keyvault
  ]
}
```

Comment: So this is by design. I see.

Comment: Jip, that is correct.